# Как реализовать property-level контроль доступа в приложении?

Tags: php, ооп, ddd

Допустим есть социальная сеть, пользователь Артём заходит на страницу своего друга Алексея. В настройках приватности Алексей разрешил видеть своим друзьям всю информацию о себе, поэтому сервер возвратит всю информацию об Алексее(кроме эмейла и пароля):

```
{
   'first_name': 'Aleksey',
   'last_name': 'Pupkin',
   'gender': 'man',
   'birthday': 08.08.1993,
   'country': 'Ukraine',
   'city': 'Kiev',
   // прочая не секретная информация 
}
```

Но также Алексей в настройках приватности запретил видеть НЕ друзьям некоторую информацию(день рождение, город проживания). Если пользователь Игорь, который не является другом Алексея, зайдёт на страницу Алексея, то сервер должен возвратить только те свойства, которые разрешено видеть Игорю. Вот так, например:

```
{
   'first_name': 'Aleksey',
   'last_name': 'Pupkin',
   'gender': 'man',
   'birthday': **null**,
   'country': Ukraine,
   'city': **null**,
   //...
}
```

То есть где-то в коде на сервере нужно решить какие свойства можно возвратить. Решаться это должно на основе настроек приватности и взаимоотношении пользователей.
Но где именно, в каком слое? Это вроде как бизнес логика или я ошибаюсь? Если да, то было бы логично поместить её в метод domain сущности или domain сервиса. Но нет, я не могу представить как можно её туда поместить. Я не представляю как можно из domain слоя возвратить user объект уже без запрещенных для показа своств. Это всего лишь чтение объекта, нужно просто возвратить ресурс(объект), здесь не должно быть бизнес логики, но она есть и она никак не вклинивается в domain слой. В этой ситуации необходим DTO, но в domain слое, по-хорошему, должны быть либо сущности, либо сервисы без состояния, но здесь не должно быть никаких DTO. DTO - это часть Application слоя.
Самое адекватное что я придумал:

1. Извлекаем объект user из БД и передаём его в какой-то класс(маппер), который
   будет создавать DTO на основе этого объекта учитывая взаимоотношения
   пользователей и настройки приватности. Минус в том, что бизнес логика находится
   в Application Service.
2. Сервер будет всегда возвращать базовый набор свойств, которые 
   разрешено просматривать абсолютно всем пользователям социальной сети. Остальные 
   свойства нужно будет запрашивать отдельно через другие URL's, там тоже нужно
   будет вычисления, но это будет намного проще, свойство либо возвращается либо 
   нет, то есть нет частичного возвращения.

Первый вариант мне нравится больше. А вам?

Comment: Первый вариант предпочтительнее. Второй вариант будет проигрывать в производительности.

Answer (score 1):

ВЫ совершенно правы, это бизнес логика, но вы заблуждаетесь на счет того, что слой доменной логики возвращает только доменные объекты. На самом деле, вы просите доменный объект вернуть информацию о себе(свое представление) на основе правил бизнес логики. И делать это должен сам доменный объект. Это можно назвать как угодно, DTO, view, info и тд.